# Deprecate components and directives in Angular

Tags: angular, eslint, angular-directive, deprecation-warning

I am currently using eslint-plugin-deprecation to mark my APIs as deprecated but I also want to mark components and directives as deprecated so that when someone tries to use it HTML they should see the deprecation note(or perhaps strikethrough?).

Using a custom directive and throwing errors/warning at runtime isn't helping because developers tend to ignore console warnings. I am looking for an option to catch these upfront at compile/build time.